# Android Google MAP V2 map.setMyLocationEnabled(true)

Tags: android

I am trying to show my current location in Google MAP using `map.setMyLocationEnabled(true)`.
 When i run the application it will always show a wrong location for first 1 - 2 min... then it will go to my current location.
It is happening every time opening the application. I want that Google MAP show my current location when i start my application.

```
map =  ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();      
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Post your code which you have implemented.

Answer (score 1):

You could apply location updates for your application when it's foreground and disable them when in background. Toggling updates in Activity `onStart` and in `onPause` using:

to request updates API is:

```
LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates
```

to remove updates API is:

```
LocationManager.removeUpdates
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I am using MAP view not location manager . So how/where i will use this.

Comment: You can place the updates to you main Activity code, onStart you requestLocationUpdates and in onPause you removeUpdates